# How to Convert Dominion Land Survey (DLS) to Latitude Longitude?

Tags: python, powerbi

Is there a python library that can convert DLS land data into latitude longitude coordinates? Alternatively does anyone know the transformations that need to be applied to DLS land codes to arrive at Latitude Longitude coordinates?

I want to convert a dataset with 100k rows of DLS data into latitude longitude coordinates.

I have attempted to use pyproj but have not been successful.

Dominion Land Survery (DLS) format:
LSD-Section-Township-Range-Meridian
7-25-24-1-W5

[image: DLS Land Format Example]

I used the pyproj library, but it has not produced accurate latitude longitude coordinates nor have i been able to figure out the precise input format required from documentation.

Comment: Is precision really an issue?  A section is about a mile square.  Do you just need a point somewhere within that square mile?  Figuring latitude is easy.  Longitude is a bear, because the lines converge as you go north.  Check this link:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136461/calculating-lat-long-coordinates-from-dls-dominion-land-survey-location